# Xamarin iOS Designer can't add adaptive font size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working on `Xamarin.iOS` project and I have used size classes to designed my app, But now I need to change the font size according to size classes (adaptive font size).

I can't find a way to do this using the Xamarin iOS designer. Unlike Xcode IB, the Xamarin iOS designer does not have `+` sign to add font constraints for required size class.

Am I missing something? I have already tried to looking through the documentation but was unsuccessful. If this is not possible in the Xamarin iOS designer, is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you using VS for windows, or XS/VS on Mac? If it's on the mac you can right click and open in interface builder and add what you need in there.

Comment: @JimBobBennett i am using XS on Mac. Thanks for the Hint. This could be the work around but i was wondering if there is any way to do it in XS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.iOS Designer is not 100 percent same as Xcode's IB, so if someone is easy with Xcode's IB, he/she can open the storyboard or nib file in Xcode right away form Xamarin.